# Amchart: Label Names in Vertical Axes Stack Charts

Tags: javascript, html, amcharts, amcharts4

The code of Vertical Stack Axes Chart is clearly documented [here](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/vertically-stacked-axes-chart/).

So I am not rewriting the code.

I was trying to put Labels to each stack as shown in this screenshot, but to no avail. Kindly help.

[image: Vertical Axes Stack with label Names]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to add a label to the value axis `renderer.gridContainer`, set their `isMeasured = false` so it's taken out of the flow of layout and doesn't interfere with anything else. You'll have to fiddle around with the layout to get it centered, but here's an example:

```js
var title = valueAxis.renderer.gridContainer.createChild(am4core.Label);
title.text =  "[bold]Price";
title.fill = series.fill;
title.isMeasured = false;
title.y = 8;
title.x = am4core.percent(50);
title.align = "center";
title.textAlign = "middle";
```

Demo:

https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/3ee9e8c1b01cc6ce4cd8ffe275b18907

Comment: @May You're welcome! Sorry for the delayed response, just saw this comment now.